# Firebase UI for Storage with Kotlin gives Error

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage, firebaseui

I am getting error while adding dependency for **firebase-ui-storage.**

I have created app for **Kotlin**

**build.gradle** - before:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.6'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0'
```

after adding:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.2.0'
```

I am getting error like:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 25.3.1, 25.1.1. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1 and
>   com.android.support:palette-v7:25.1.1
>
> There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that
>   are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is
>   compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not
>   the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion.)

I dont know why it happens even I dont have used **vector drawable or palette**

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use  `./gradlew app:dependencies`  on linux or mac or `gradlew.bat app:dependencies` on windows using a terminal on android studio to see the dependency tree and then you can update to the latest versions or force use the latest version

Comment: and then you can add `configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1"}`. to make sure all other libs use the same support lib. Just add for other libs as well

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had the same issue. So I downgraded the versions to these:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.4'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.4'
```

and it worked fine for me.

But if you want to know what's wrong with your current dependencies, probably you should see what your full tree of dependencies is and from there, you will see which one of your libraries is asking for a different version of the Android Support libraries.